# Strange behavior in columns that are not null and have default values (SpringBoot JPA)

Tags: jpa

Discovering a strange behavior during SpringBoot JPA testing
Please advise.
What I want is a column that has a default value and is not null.
I created it like this

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Board {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long seq;

    @Column(length = 320, nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("'system'")
    /* i don't won't it this way */
//    @Builder.Default
//    private String usrId = "system";
    private String usrId;
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJpaTestApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootJpaTestApplication.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJpaTestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner demo(TestRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
//                Test test = Test.builder().build();
                Test test = new Test();
                test.setTitle("test title " + i);
                test.setContent("test content " + i);
                
                System.out.println(test.toString());
                
                repository.save(test);
            }
            
            repository.findAll().forEach(test -> {
                log.info(test.toString());
            });
            
            repository.findByTitle("test").forEach(bbs -> {
                log.info(bbs.toString());
            });
            
        };
    }

}
```

This seemed to work fine.
However, if you comment out the following, an error occurs

```
<!--
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
-->
```

Error description

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-03-14T23:09:48.901+09:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m2776[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[SpringBootJpaTest] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;
39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.demo.SpringBootJpa.Test.usrId
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2
.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy94.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.skywhalelab.SpringBootJpa.SpringBootJpaTestApplication.lambda$0(SpringBootJpaTestApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at com.skywhalelab.SpringBootJpa.SpringBootJpaTestApplication.main(SpringBootJpaTestApplication.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Can you tell me why this is happening?
Of course, I know that if I use Builder.Default and give it a default value, it works fine.
But that's not the direction I want to go.
I want to handle it so that if usrId goes to null, I don't get an error and the DB puts in the Default value.

Thank you in advance.

---

---

---

Thank you for your answer.

Let me clarify my question further.

In JPA, if the @DynamicInsert annotation is present and the Entity has a field with a null value, it will not be included when inserting.

It works like this

```
Hibernate: 
    create table test (
        del_yn varchar(1) default 'N' not null,
        dth integer default 0,
        rd_cnt integer default 0 not null,
        bbs_cd varchar(8) default 'NONE',
        cre_dt datetime(6) default sysdate() not null,
        mod_dt datetime(6),
        seq bigint not null,
        upr_seq bigint,
        title varchar(128),
        usr_id varchar(320) default 'system' not null,
        content tinytext,
        primary key (seq)
    ) engine=InnoDB
[2m2024-03-16T07:51:16.144+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6540[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[SpringBootJpaTest] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mj.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean[0;
39m [2m:[0;39m Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[2m2024-03-16T07:51:16.470+09:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6540[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[SpringBootJpaTest] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mc.s.S.SpringBootJpaTestApplication      [0;
39m [2m:[0;39m Started SpringBootJpaTestApplication in 7.923 seconds (process running for 8.568)
Test(seq=null, bbsCd=null, title=test title 0, content=test content 0, uprSeq=null, rdCnt=null, dth=null, delYn=null, usrId=null, creDt=null, modDt=null)
Hibernate: 
    select
        next value for test_seq
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        test
        (content, title, seq) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
```

This works perfectly fine.

In other words, if usrId is Null, it is not included in the Insert syntax.

This is because of the @DynamicInsert annotation.

However, if we remove the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency, we get an error.

Here is what is commonly known

1. if [nullable = false] in the @Column annotation, make the table column [not null].
2. if entity have the @DynamicInsert annotation, if the value of a particular field is Null, remove that field from the Insert syntax.

The difference between having spring-boot-starter-validation in pom.xml and not having it is as follows

The prerequisites are

1. the @DynamicInsert annotation is declared.

- If the @DynamicInsert annotation is not declared, ColumnDefault is meaningless.

2. the column has [nullable = false] declared.

- A specific column must be created as [not null].

3. the corresponding field (in this case usrId) is null.

In this case, the following happens

1. spring-boot-starter-validation, if present, will not check for null.

- Since there is a DynamicInsert annotation, usrId is not included in the Insert syntax and the default value "system" is inserted.

2. if spring-boot-starter-validation is not present, it checks null and raises an error.

For example, this column behaves as follows when null.

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private String testColumn;
```

without spring-boot-starter-validation, it will be checked for not-null and an error will be thrown. Same behaviour as above.

If spring-boot-starter-validation is present, it is not included in the Insert syntax due to the @DynamicInsert annotation.

However, the table column is not assigned Default, so an error is thrown.

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [(conn=1624) Field 'test_column' doesn't have a default value] [insert into test (content,title,seq) values (?,?,?)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
```

To summarize, my question is this.

1. the entity has the @DynamicInsert annotation declared.
2. a certain field has @Column(nullable = false) declared on it.
3. the specific field value is null.

- If the spring-boot-starter-validation dependency is not present in the pom.xml, the null check will result in an error.
- If there is a spring-boot-starter-validation dependency in the pom.xml, it does not check null.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've uploaded the source I tested to git.

If you could take a look and give me some advice, it would be greatly appreciated :)

git: github.com/jykim31337/SpringBootJpaTest.git

Comment: I have additionally edited and posted the answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also didn't quite understand the intent of the problem. thank you :)

The cause of the problem lies in the hibernate.check_nullability check method.

@Column(nullable=false) is a Hibernate annotation.

- To conclude, the annotation is involved in validation.
- It may be tricky, but if you refer to the Hibernate official document, there is a property called hibernate.check_nullability.

  - The main thing is that if **Bean Validation** is on the class path (i.e.'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation') and the Hibernate annotation is used, **the default value is false, no validation is made.** The opposite is true, the validation is made.
- In summary, spring-boot-starter-validation(hibernate) has been added and @Column(nullable=false) has been applied, so @DynamicInsert is applied without null check.
- On the other hand, when spring-boot-starter-validation is deleted, Bean Validation is not in the classpath, so Hibernate checks for nullability and throws a PropertyValueException exception.

I verified it with the example below. :)

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

//    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Board {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long seq;

    @Column(length = 320, nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("'system'")
    private String usrId;
}
```

Create a custom Hibernate configuration class, change the check_nullability property to false, and run it.

```java
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {
        return hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties.put(Environment.CHECK_NULLABILITY, false);
    }
}
```

```java
//skip logic...
Board board = new Board();
boardRepository.save(board);
//...
```

- @DynamicInsert is applied.

```java
Hibernate: 
    select
        next value for board_seq
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        board
        (seq) 
    values
        (?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.seq,
        b1_0.usr_id 
    from
        board b1_0
```

I hope it will be of help.

---

- From a DBMS perspective, it is natural that NULL constraints have priority over default.

  - DBMS is a system that places data integrity above all else.

Let's briefly summarize the flow with and without the NULL constraint below.

- nullable = true(NULL constraint X)

  - usrId(null) → DBMS → usrID(system) → INSERT
- nullable = false (NULL constraint O)

  - usrId(null) → DBMS → exception!(Do not enter null!)

However, there is something that can be a bit confusing.

- Column default enters the corresponding value as default if the column is not entered in the insert query.

  - This is completely different from changing a null value to a default value.
- Let’s see the differences below.

```sql
INSERT INTO BOARD(SEQ) VALUES(1); //this case insert default value in USR_ID
INSERT INTO BOARD(SEQ, USR_ID) VALUES(4, null); //NULL not allowed for column
```

- If you try to input a null value into a SQL query, a NULL not allowed for column error will occur.

  - This is because it violates the NULL constraint.

In conclusion, JPA does not work as the questioner intended.

- This is because JPA also uses the same exception handling as DBMS.

  - I think this is to ensure system stability by handling exceptions in advance at the application stage before a request goes to the DBMS and an error occurs.

#### Recommended solution

- First, when creating an object, I prefer to create and use the object by setting the initial value of the corresponding value in the constructor.

  - Reason 1: It is more object-oriented.
  - Reason 2: It does not depend on JPA, but rather on programming languages, so it is not dependent on any specific technology.

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class Board {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long seq;

    @Column(length = 320, nullable = false)
    @ColumnDefault("'system'")
    private String usrId;

    public Board(String userId) {
        if (userId == null || userId.isEmpty()) {
            this.usrId = "system";
            return;
        }
        this.usrId = userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I think my question was not clear enough.

Let me clarify my question further.

Comment: I understand why.
Thank you so much for your kind response!